# What is the Maximum Allowed File Size for downloading using NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

Part of the functionality Ive written for an app is downloading zip files from a server using NSMutableURLRequest. All works until I try to download a file approx greater than 12MB.
The iPhone is on wireless lan.
I was wondering if there is a limit or max chunk size to implement when downloading larger files?
I fails for these file sizes on both simulator and device. The application just crashes and 
didFailWithError connection delegate is never hit.

Ive been stumped by this for days now :(
Your help is much appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely getting low memory warning and that cause application to crash. Check [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623735/how-to-download-a-large-file-with-the-iphone-sdk-and-avoid-memory-usage-issues) - you can write the data you recieve directly into file, rather then into memory. You can use NSFileHandle class for that.