# how to parse part of xml with NSURLconnection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection for loading the data and parse with nsxmlparser. Currently I let the whole data is loaded then I parse it but for improving the speed I would like to know how I can parse section of data which is received in didReceiveData delegate method. If I just move my parsing function in this method I would get error since when it breaks to different parts it doesn't have XML correct format or...

I would appreciate if some one could help me in anyway in case of improving the speed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094) that should help you in improving performance. It parses xml data on the fly. You need to check in `iTunesRSSParser` and `LibXMLParser` if you want to use libXMl2 parser. and change according. There is also a way using `NSXMLParser` you can try that too. `libxml2` would be a better way though.

Comment: +1 Agreed. LibXML2 seems to work fine. I'm not crazy about the sample code in that [XMLPerformance sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094), but the LibXML2 approach definitely avoids the problems with `NSXMLParser`.

Answer (score 0):

Check:
[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

It has code for 7 different ways of XML parsing and has them set up so you can test there efficiency it is worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you will still need to download the whole file whether you will like to parse a part or the whole.

Memory wise and speed wise it will be best to save it locally and then parse the part that you want to parse. I haven't tried but I think it is possible for you to open the file and go to the part you want to parse.

Check this question it has an answer of what I am talking about

[How to download a large file with the iPhone SDK and avoid memory usage issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623735/how-to-download-a-large-file-with-the-iphone-sdk-and-avoid-memory-usage-issues)